# Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet]

Tags: spring, spring-boot, maven, tomcat9

I configured spring boot project in eclipse and encountered the error below while trying to run it. Please what is the solution
Error message:

```
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@10f384a2]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:841)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:421)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:633)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:475)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.JarResourceSet@10f384a2]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:139)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:173)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:724)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4797)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4932)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.read(Native Method)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile.access$1400(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.ZipFile$ZipFileInflaterInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.IOUtils.readFully(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getBytes(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifestFromReference(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.jar.JarFile.getManifest(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.initInternal(AbstractSingleArchiveResourceSet.java:141)
```

The server is tomcat 9. I have checked many solutions online but seems not to address the problem.

Comment: This information is incomplete. You need to look further in the logs. Try reading yourself, it says *"A child container failed during start"* but it does nowhere say why it failed. You need to find that in the logs. That will be your answer.

Comment: ok let me paste the whole error

Comment: For starters, the stack trace is possibly composed of multiple causes. The top cause is caused by the bottom cause. So the most bottom cause is the cause of everything in top. So the most bottom cause is the most important one to understand and solve.

Answer (score 4):

One of the jar files that is on the classpath of your application is corrupted. This is causing a failure when Tomcat tries to access the manifest in that jar file: `java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)`.

Unfortunately, Tomcat hasn't said which jar file it was trying to access when the failure occurred. You could figure that out by placing a breakpoint in the `ZipException(String)` constructor and then running your application in the debugger. Alternatively, working on the assumption that Maven has corrupted one of your application's dependencies when it downloaded it, you could delete Maven's cache and rebuild your application. This will cause Maven to download the jar file again and it hopefully won't corrupt it this time.

Comment: This happens simply because no checksum policy is used. https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2018/10/13/maven-artifact-checksums-what/

Comment: Thanks for the response, I will try this